# Sort columns after rows correlation

Tags: python, correlation

I have a pandas dataframe with two or more rows and 42 columns. By transposing and plotting it, I get the profiles of the rows.

```
df.T.plot()
```

[image]

I want to sort the columns, so that first there are the columns, where the rows are strongly correlated (similar profile, values go in the same direction) and later the columns, where the rows have a weak correlation (opposite profile, values go in opposite direction).

I could run a cluster algorithm on the columns, but clusters are not exactly what I want.

I think one solution would be to sort after the distance of the points from the linear regression line??
[image]

Comment: Just Compute the Pearson Correlation Coefficient and use that in the sort. See http://www.stat.wmich.edu/s216/book/node122.html for  how to do it.

Comment: I only get one PCC. How I decide on the order then?

Answer (score 0):

Correlation is a measure that describes the relationship between two variables in total, not at specific points. The metric you've described for sorting isn't correlation, but rather the absolute difference between the column values in the two rows. (With the transpose operation the two rows become two columns, and their lines on the graph you're making will 'go in the opposite direction" when the values in the two columns are further away from each other.)

Achieving this with the dataframe you've described would look something like:

```
df_T = df.T
df_T['sort_column'] = df_T.panB - df_T.panC
df_T.sort_values('sort_column', inplace=True)
df_T.drop('sort_column', inplace=True)
df_T.plot()
```

Comment: Yes, my metric is false. So I need another one. Another solution would be to  calculate the PCC and then remove one point and than calculate the PCC again. Do this test for every point and look, where the PCC increases the most. Then remove this point and sort it to the far left. Repeat this until you have only two points left.
This would be computational expensive, but it would probably do what I need. Isn´t there another way?

Comment: I think the solution is simpler than that. As I understand it, you want the top graph sorted based on the distance between the blue and green lines, so that they diverge from left to right?

The absolute value of the difference (subtraction) in the rows is the metric to use for your desired behavior. The value of | panC - panB | calculated for each column's pair of values in the original dataframe is the distance between the lines on your first graph.

Comment: I don´t think, it´s that easy. I want to sort them so that at the right the profile correlates good. The PCC is invariant to the distance. It only cares about the similar direction of value changes. So at the right there needs to be highly correlated Profile (the subset would have the highest correlation) and then the values that decrease that correlation on the left

Comment: What you're asking to do doesn't have anything to do with using 'correlation' in the technical sense. PCC describes the relationship between ALL values of a pair of variables as a single number between -1 and 1 --this isn't what you're trying to do, since you're just comparing two values on the line at a given point. How does the code I provided compare to the desired behavior?